# Cookie Law EU - Create a popup for blocking interaction

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

Hi there's a big mess around with this new cookie law.

Most websites nowdays are made in wordpress and there's a bunch of plugins inside. The majority of those cookie plugins just show a banner, or asks the developer to mark with a shortcode each cookie code in the website, so its loading can be prevented with a script.

But for an average website, with a bunch of plugins inside, its a huge work! We should read the code of each plugin and mark all the cookie code. isn't it crazy work to do?

wouldn't it be better to just add a popup that will totally block interaction till the user accept the policy? ( just like this website http://www.ilsole24ore.com/ )

Is there a plugin for doing this? i found a nice script 
http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog
for blocking the ui... but how can save the user preference so it won't appear anymore after the user click it once?

is this a good solution for comply to the cookie eu law?

Comment: Ironically, to save the user preference you will need to store a cookie on the users machine to say they have accepted and not show it again!

Comment: do you think it is a good solution? i noticed that most websites around have just the banner, but it doesn't really block much.  the only plugins that block the cookies require to manually wrap them inside a shortcode, but it's a huge work to do...

Comment: Please see my answer. To be fair the EU cookie law is a lot of hot air and many big name sites do not comply to it. Its a pathetic law at best! To my knowledge NO ONE has yet been arrested, killed, fined, beaten due to non-compliance! 

A simple cookie policy page on your site usually can suffice, but if you wish to block UI access thne please see my answer.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think _"Most websites nowdays are made in wordpress"_ is really true.  And I speak as someone who develops sites in WordPress!